# Swift : Share image using UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, uiactivityviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to share QR image on tap of button using `ActivityViewController`.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Below is code that I’ve used :

```
@IBAction func btnShareQRCode_Clicked(sender: UIButton) {
        self.shareQRCodeUsingActivityViewController(self.imageviewQRCode.image!)
    }

func shareQRCodeUsingActivityViewController(imageParamater: UIImage) {
        let activityItem: [UIImage] = [imageParamater as UIImage]

        let objActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: activityItem as [UIImage], applicationActivities: nil)
        objActivityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeAirDrop, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList]

        // objActivityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = sender
        self.presentViewController(objActivityViewController, animated: true, completion: {
            objActivityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in

                if !success { print("cancelled")
                    return
                }

                if activity == UIActivityTypeMail {
                    print("mail")
                }
                else if activity == UIActivityTypeMessage {
                    print("message")
                }
                else if activity == UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll {
                    print("camera")
                }
            }
        })
    }

    func completionHandler() {
    }
```

The issue with this is that it is getting crashed on mail stating an error regarding MailComposer.

I want to know how and where these MailComposer function should be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running this on iOS Simulator, Mail component is likely to fail.

Apart from that, I don't think you need to cast your activity items list as `UIImage`. Simply put an array of objects as a `activityItems` array.